# Loop unknown depth multidimensional array in flutter from JSON

Tags: arrays, loops, flutter, dart, multidimensional-array

I have an array and this array i get from JSON, but this array is not known how deep and i just want to make it 2 dimensions parrent and children. I make the example just 3 dimensions but in real case it can be unknown.

This array have same object from parent and children. You can see the exampale here.

From this :

```
{
  "brand_id": "1",
  "name": "Civic",
  "type": "Sedan",
  "children": [
    {
      "brand_id": "1",
      "name": "Civic Type-R",
      "type": "Sedan",
      "children": [
        {
          "brand_id": "1",
          "name": "Civic Type-R 2020",
          "type": "Sedan",
          "children": [
            {
              "brand_id": "1",
              "name": "Civic Type-R 2020 A",
              "type": "Sedan"
            },
            {
              "brand_id": "1",
              "name": "Civic Type-R 2020 B",
              "type": "Sedan"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "brand_id": "1",
          "name": "Civic Type-R 2019",
          "type": "Sedan",
          "children": [
            {
              "brand_id": "1",
              "name": "Civic Type-R 2019 A",
              "type": "Sedan"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I hope from example can be like this :

```
{
  "brand_id": "1",
  "name": "Civic",
  "type": "Sedan",
  "children": [
    {
      "brand_id": "1",
      "name": "Civic Type-R",
      "type": "Sedan"
    },
    {
      "brand_id": "1",
      "name": "Civic Type-R 2020",
      "type": "Sedan"
    },
    {
      "brand_id": "1",
      "name": "Civic Type-R 2020 A",
      "type": "Sedan"
    },
    {
      "brand_id": "1",
      "name": "Civic Type-R 2020 B",
      "type": "Sedan"
    },
    {
      "brand_id": "1",
      "name": "Civic Type-R 2019",
      "type": "Sedan"
    },
    {
      "brand_id": "1",
      "name": "Civic Type-R 2019 A",
      "type": "Sedan"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a simpler example or at least format it properly. It is very hard to read and see the difference.

Comment: Hi @Ridcully thanks for the reply, can you format the example json using viewer?

Comment: Please also format the first JSON so we can see the differences better

Comment: Ok done @Ridcully

Answer (score 0):

**Model Class**

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

class MyModel {

  String brand_id;
  String name;
  String type;

  List<ChildrenModel> children;

  MyModel({
    this.brand_id,
    this.name,
    this.type,
    this.children,
  });

  factory MyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new MyModel(
      brand_id: json['brand_id'].toString(),
      name: json['name'].toString(),
      type: json['type'].toString(),
      children: (json['children']  as List).map((i) => ChildrenModel.fromJson(i)).toList(),
    );
  }


}

class ChildrenModel {

  String brand_id;
  String name;
  String type;

  ChildrenModel({
    this.brand_id,
    this.name,
    this.type,
  });

  factory ChildrenModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new ChildrenModel(
      brand_id: json['brand_id'].toString(),
      name: json['name'].toString(),
      type: json['type'].toString(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the same class object inside a class

```
class Brand{
  String id;
  String name;
  Strng type;
  List<Brand> children;

  Brand({this.id, this.name, this.type, this.children});

   Brand.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['brand_id'];
    name = json['name'];
    type = json['type'];
    if (json['children'] != null) {
      children = new List<Brand>();
      json['children'].forEach((v) {
        children.add(Brand.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['brand_id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    if (this.children != null) {
      data['children'] = this.children.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

Create your model like this and convert the json accordingly.